# Apple like mouse hover-zoom cursor

Tags: jquery, html

Apple has a pretty cool feature when hovering over a large image here: http://www.apple.com/aperture/what-is.html It zooms out a small magnifier glass icon which moves with the cursor while over a zoomable image.

How can I do that, preferably with JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use CSS like so:

```
cursor: url(pix/cursor_ppk.gif), auto.
```

see here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html

Comment: ?? How will the cursor dynamically change to follow the source image as the cursor moves?

Comment: Awesome solution, but no IE support according to that chart? Uhg.

Comment: What about effects like zooming or fading the cursor?

Answer (score 1):

Setup an event handler in jQuery for mouseenter() and mouseleave().

During mouseenter(), show the zoom icon and hide it when mouseleave() fires. You should implement these two states with CSS classes. The zoom icon should be absolutely positioned and its positioning container should be the the body of the web page.

Then, implement the mousemove() event over the image. Inside this function, set the absolute position of the zoom icon so it's always a little up and over from the current mouse position.

**Sample Event Bindings**

```
$('.someImage').bind('mouseenter', function () {

    $('#zoomIcon').addClass('over');

}).bind('mouseleave', function () {

    $('#zoomIcon').removeClass('over');

}).bind('mousemove', function (e) {

    $('#zoomIcon').css('top', e.clientY-40).css('left', e.clientX);

});
```

This gets you the zoom icon behavior. The click event behavior is just a couple more lines. The following code shows a hand-made zoom feature that makes use of the new css3 rules. This code is built for webkit, but you can easily add the other browser specific rules to get good cross browser support.

The zoom feature examines the position of the mouse click and converts that position into one of four quadrants. You could split the image into more quadrants if you wanted to. Then, once the quadrant is known, you set the absolute position and change the height/width of the image. The css3 transition property slows down the height/width change so you get a nice zoom feature.

**Sample Zoom Behavior**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
    <title>sample zoom</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <style> 
        #zoomContainer,
        #zoomContainer img {
            height:300px;
            width:400px;
        }
        #zoomContainer img {
            -transition-property: height,width;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 3s;
            position:absolute;
        }
        #zoomContainer {
            background:#F00;
            overflow:hidden;
            position:relative;
            border:1px solid #000;
        }
        #zoomContainer.over {
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        #zoomContainer img.zoom {
            width:962px;
            height:517px;
        }
    </style> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        /* my custom jQuery extension */

        (function ($) {

            $.fn.setPositionByQuadrant = function (quadrant) {

                switch (quadrant) {

                    case 1:
                    this.removeAttr('style').css('top', 0).css('left', 0);
                    break;

                    case 2:
                    this.removeAttr('style').css('top', 0).css('right', 0);
                    break;

                    case 3:
                    this.removeAttr('style').css('bottom', 0).css('left', 0);
                    break;

                    case 4:
                    this.removeAttr('style').css('bottom', 0).css('right', 0);
                    break;
                }

                return this;
            };

        })(jQuery);

        /* page specific javascript */

        $(function () {

            $('#zoomContainer').mouseenter(function () {
                $(this).addClass('over');
            }).mouseleave(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('over');
            }).mousemove(function () {
                // change position of zoom icon here
            }).click(function (e) {
                var quadrant = convertClickPositionToQuadrant(e, $(this));
                var img = $(this).find('img').toggleClass('zoom').setPositionByQuadrant(quadrant);
            });

        });

        /* conversion function */

        function convertClickPositionToQuadrant(e,target) {

            var x = e.offsetX;
            var y = e.offsetY;

            var xMiddle = target.width() / 2;
            var yMiddle = target.height() / 2;

            if (x > xMiddle) {
                if (y > yMiddle)
                    return 4;
                else
                    return 2;

            } else {
                if (y > yMiddle)
                    return 3;
                else
                    return 1;
            }
        }

    </script> 

</head> 

<body> 

    <h2>Sample Zoom</h2>

    <div id="zoomContainer">
        <img src="http://dots.physics.orst.edu/graphics/image_maps/usa_map.gif" alt="" /> 
    </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hm... looks nice. but what about the zooming effect of the magnifier glass? The lightbox effect is already done. My problem is the smal cursor icon + zoom effect of the CURSOR... any ideas on that?

Comment: Apple looks like they're employing a zoom library: http://images.apple.com/global/scripts/zoomerlay.js, but you can search for "jQuery image zoom" and find a bunch for that library too.

Comment: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/02/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-stunning-image-zoom-effects.html

Comment: Thanks for the links. I already did that, the plugins are all for Zooming the IMAGE. I am looking for a solution to zoom the mouse cursor when hovering over the thumbnail image

Comment: Sorry, just saw this comment "zoom the mouse cursor". What does that mean to you? I see the mouse pointer change into a magnifying glass when the overlay is present. And the mouse pointer has the balloon next to it when the overlay is not present. I'm not sure what you mean in the Apple example. It seems like cursor: url(pix/cursor_ppk.gif), auto. will get the custom mouse icon for you, except it doesn't work in IE.